# Question about proof-correctness of FLT for n = 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, diophantine-equations

Anything wrong with the following?

**Theorem:**

$\quad$ Let:

$\quad\quad \gcd(x,y,z) = 1$,

$\quad$ Then:

$\quad\quad x^3 = y^3 + z^3$ has no non-zero integer solutions for $(x,y,z)$

**Proof:**

$\quad$ Assuming $3 \nmid x - y \implies 3 \nmid z$ and making use of the following equation:

$\quad\quad x^3 - y^3 = 3x^2(x - y) - (2x + y)(x - y)^2$

$\quad$ which is verifiable by working out parentheses,

$\quad\quad \implies (x^3 - y^3)/(x - y) = 3x^2 - (2x + y)(x - y)$

$\quad\quad \implies (2x + y)(x - y) \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$

$\quad$ Suppose now $3 \not | y$ and the same holds for $x - z$ we also have:

$\quad\quad \implies (2x + z)(x - z) \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$

$\quad\quad \implies (2x + y)(x - y) \equiv (2x + z)(x - z) \pmod{3}$

$\quad\quad \implies (2x + y)z \equiv (2x + z)y \pmod{3}$

$\quad\quad \implies 2xz \equiv 2xy \pmod{3}$

$\quad\quad \implies y \equiv z \pmod{3}$

$\quad\quad \implies y^3 \equiv z^3 \pmod{9}$

$\quad\quad \implies x^3 \equiv y^3 + z^3 \equiv 2y^3 \pmod{9}$

$\quad\quad \implies (x/y)^3 \equiv 2 \pmod{9}$

$\quad$ which is impossible because of $2$ not being a cubic residue $\pmod{9}$.

$\quad$ So now we know $3$ divides either $y$ or $z$ but not both.

$\quad$ Suppose $3|z \implies 3|x - y$, and note:

$\quad\quad\quad\quad \gcd(x - y,z^3/(x - y))$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad = \gcd(x - y,(x^3 - y^3)/(x - y))$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad = \gcd(x - y,3x^2) = 3$

$\quad$ so we know $9 \nmid x - y$.

$\quad$ Take the following equation:

$\quad\quad (x - y)^3 + 3y(x - y)^2 + 3y^2(x - y) = x^3 - y^3 = z^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{27}$

$\quad\quad \implies 3y^2(x - y) \equiv 0 \pmod{27} \implies 3 | y$

$\quad$ contradicting $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$

$\quad$ The conclusion is there cannot be any solutions at all.

Comment: You seem to be missing the cases where $3$ *does* divide $x-y$.  You should note that nowhere did you use the fact that $x,y,z$ should be positive integers.  There *is* a solution in the integers, namely where $x=y=z=0$, and your "proof" would have somehow proven that $x^3$ cannot equal $y^3+z^3$ even when they are all zero somehow and so clearly has errors.

Comment: There exist other solutions as well if we don't enforce that all are strictly positive, for example $0^3=(-2)^3+(2)^3$, and here we have a situation where $3\nmid x-y$ yet we still have a valid solution, which shows that even the work that you did do is incorrect.  Even with the edit, $\gcd(0,-1,1)=1$ and $0^3=(-1)^3+(1)^3$ and runs into the same problem.

Comment: There's a blunder just after "$3\nmid x-y$", The congruence should be $x-y\equiv-(2x+y)(x-y)^2$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Your comments are not very useful to me. Please try not to demotivate people and share insights instead of complaining.

Comment: Complaining?  I should have thought that it was constructive criticism.  I'm sorry that I didn't take your feelings into consideration when posting, but usually people are only concerned with facts in maths. If there is evidence that an argument is flawed, the evidence should be presented and that is just what I've done above. If your issue with what I've posted is that I only confirmed that your argument was flawed and that I didn't offer any suggestion on how to correct it, then you should have clarified that this was what you wanted in your post. You asked only if your argument was correct.

Comment: You still have the statement of the theorem you are trying to prove is false, which I will reiterate that any attempt to prove a false statement must have some error in the proof somewhere.  There do exist solutions $(x,y,z)$ in the integers where $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$ and $x^3=y^3+z^3$, as pointed out above.  Attempting to correct a proof to a false statement is futile, because no correct proof could exist.

Comment: Sorry for that but I thought it was assumed that we are talking about non-zero solutions when FLT is mentioned. If these are your only arguments then I am satisfied. I mean these are easily fixable.

Comment: I will refer you again to my first comment.  You make no mention anywhere *during* your proof that $x,y,z$ should be positive integers.  If a proof to a statement which although true with certain hypotheses is false without those hypotheses does not make use of said hypotheses, then it cannot be correct.  I have not yet taken the time to comb through your proof to point out specific steps that are incorrect because your proof still has not passed the basic tests.  Looking at it in a bit more detail, I still do not have to go far because you begin "Suppose $x-y\nmid 3\implies z\nmid3$."

Comment: You then have a separate case where assume $z\mid3 \implies x-y\mid 3$.  These two cases are logically equivalent, they are simply contrapositives of one another.  You have not touched on the remaining cases where $x-y\mid 3$ but $z\nmid 3$ and so on, which even if trivial still needs to be mentioned.  Looking a line further, you have a division by a phrase involving variables, yet you did not account for the possibility of this giving a division by zero error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall not edit but answer to my own question and prove only the first case of FLT for $n = 3$ in a more correct way. I have no idea for the second case.

It is easier to take the last equation and prove the first case in the following way:

**Theorem**:

Let:

$\quad x,y,z$ be none-zero integers

$\quad \gcd(x,y,z) = 1$

$\quad 3 \nmid xyz$

Then:

$\quad x^3 \neq y^3 + z^3$

**Proof**:

$\quad$Consider:

$\quad\quad x^3 - y^3 = 3y^2(x - y) + 3y(x - y)^2 + (x - y)^3 = z^3$

$\quad \implies \gcd((x^3 - y^3)/(x - y),x - y) = \gcd(x - y,3y^2) = 1$

$\quad \implies x - y = r^3$ and $(x^3 - y^3)/(x - y) = s^3$,

$\quad\quad$for some $r,s$ with $\gcd(r,s) = 1$ and $z = rs$

$\quad$Because of:

$\quad\quad s^3 \equiv (x^3 - y^3)/(x - y) \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$

$\quad$and:

$\quad\quad x - y \equiv r^3 \implies (x - y)^2 \equiv r^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$

$\quad$We have:

$\quad\quad s^3 \equiv 3y^2 + 3y(x - y) + r^6 \pmod{9}$

$\quad \implies 1 \equiv 3y^2 + 3y(x - y) + 1 \pmod{9}$

$\quad \implies 3y^2 + 3y(x - y) \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$

$\quad \implies y^2 + y(x - y) \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$

$\quad \implies yx \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$

$\quad\quad$Which is impossible because of $3 \nmid xyz$.

Comment: Why must $x-y$ equal a cube?  I see that it is a convenient outcome if it happens to be true, but you have not proven that $x-y$ couldn't equal a noncube, e.g. $x-y=4$.

Comment: I think because $gcd(r,s) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

> Claim: Let $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$ and let none of $x,y,z$ be zero. then $x^3\neq y^3+z^3$.
>
> **Proof:**
>
> (*Suppose otherwise that $x^3=y^3+z^3$ has a solution*)
>
> Assuming $3\nmid x-y\implies 3\nmid z$...

Assuming $3\mid z$ this implies that $3^3\mid z^3$ implying $3^3\mid x^3-y^3$ and $3^3\mid (x-y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$.  This does not directly imply that $3\mid (x-y)$ as it could still be that $3^3\mid (x^2-xy+y^2)$, so your assumption is not necessarily a true assumption.  This implies we will need to make more assumptions later on to cover the cases missed by having made these assumptions.  Also, this is as good a time to point out as any that your assumption that $3\nmid x-y\implies 3\nmid z$ is the exact same assumption as $3\mid z\implies 3\mid x-y$.  They are contrapositives to one another and need not appear as assumptions twice in the same proof.

Further, it is often ineffecient to use implications as assumptions when doing case work.  It can be confusing and misleading.  The assumption "$3\nmid x-y\implies 3\nmid z$" is logically equivalent to "$3\mid x-y$ **or** $3\nmid z$."  Possibly both, possibly only one or the other.

> ...Assuming $3\nmid x-y\implies 3\nmid z$ and making use of the following equation $$x^3-y^3=3x^2(x-y)-(2x+y)(x-y)^2$$
>
> which is verifiable by working out parentheses,
>
> $\implies (x^3-y^3)/(x-y)=3x^2-(2x+y)(x-y)$

Division by zero error here.  In the case that $x=y$ this is not true.  You would have an undefined expression on the left and any number possible on the right.  If we did have $x=y$ though, this would imply $z=0$.  Still, this should be pointed out by the proof writer, not left as a detail for the reader.

> $\implies (2x+y)(x-y)\equiv -1\pmod{3}$

How?  In your assumptions, you effectively assumed $3\mid x-y$ or $3\nmid z$.  If it was the first, then the above is false as $(2x+y)(x-y)\equiv 0\pmod{3}$ not $-1\pmod{3}$.  If it was the second, we would have $3x^2-\frac{x^3-y^3}{x-y}=3x^2-\frac{z^3}{x-y}=(2x+y)(x-y)^2$.

Assuming the second then, $3\nmid z$ implying $3\nmid z^3$, so we learn that $3\nmid x-y$ since the expression on the right is an integer and otherwise the expression on the left wouldn't be.  Looking at this in terms of modulo3 we have $-\frac{z^3}{x-y}\equiv (2x+y)(x-y)^2\pmod{3}$.  Knowing $3\nmid z$ either $z$ can be $1$ or $-1$ mod3 and similarly, knowing $3\nmid x-y$ then $x-y$ is either $1$ or $-1$ mod3 as well, however no work has been done yet to show how they relate to one another.  From the work shown, we can make the claim that $(2x+y)(x-y)\equiv \pm 1\pmod{3}$ but it does not follow from work shown that $(2x+y)(x-y)\equiv \color{red}{-}1\pmod{3}$

> Suppose now $3\nmid y$ and the same holds for $x-z$ we also have:

What?  "*and the same holds for $x-z$*"... so we are currently working in the very restrictive set of assumptions that $(3\mid x-y$ or $3\nmid z)$ and $(3\nmid y)$ and $(3\nmid x-z)$?  We were missing some cases already for the main set of case work, now we're missing subcases within a case.

> $\implies (2x+z)(x-z)\equiv -1\pmod{3}$

As you wrote them, your hypotheses are not symmetrical, as the first set of hypotheses allowed for $3\mid x-y$, but your most recent added hypotheses you do not allow $3\mid x-z$.  As we saw before, if you did allow $3\mid x-z$ we would have not been able to reach $(2x+z)(x-z)\equiv \pm 1\pmod{3}$.  As before though, we have not successfully shown that it must be *negative* one, as it could still be positive one mod3.

By ignoring this, your argument continues:

> $\implies (2x+y)(x-y)\equiv (2x+z)(x-z)\pmod{3}$
>
> $\implies (2x+y)z\equiv (2x+z)y\pmod{3}$

I do not follow how this substitution was made.  We have done no work in showing that $z\equiv x-y\pmod{3}$ and our hypotheses do not imply this.  Removing the part of the first assumption that led to a contradiction (*which the contradiction could have been explained by the division by zero error rather than the assumption itself*), we would have $3\nmid x-y$ and $3\nmid z$ simultaneously, but that doesn't mean that $x-y\equiv z\pmod{3}$.  We could have $x-y\equiv 1\not\equiv -1\equiv z\pmod{3}$ or vice versa.

> $\implies 2xz\equiv 2xy\pmod{3}$
>
> $\implies y\equiv z\pmod{3}$

"Dividing" by two is fine here because two is not a zero in mod3 arithmetic, but division by $x$ is not allowed for fear of division by zero errors.  The correct result here would be $3\mid x$ or $y\equiv z\pmod{3}$.  You have not done work to imply that $3\nmid x$ to discount this case and this was not included in any of your hypotheses so far.

Ignoring this again for now and continuing...

> $\implies y^3\equiv z^3\pmod{9}$
>
> $\implies x^3\equiv y^3+z^3\equiv 2y^3\pmod{9}$
>
> $\implies (x/y)^3\equiv 2\pmod{9}$

This step of "dividing" by $y$ is only *okay* because our assumptions included $3\nmid y$.  It is incorrect however to write it as a fraction.  The more correct way to write this would be $(x\cdot y^{-1})^3\equiv 2\pmod{3}$

> which is impossible because of $2$ not being a cubic residue mod9.  So now we know $3$ divides either $y$ or $z$ but not both.

The bit about $2$ not being a cubic residue is fine, but how do we know that $3$ divides either $y$ or $z$ but not both?  All of our work so far has been under the assumption that $3$ did *not* divide either of $y$ or $z$, so how can any of it have any influence on the validity of the cases where $3$ *does* divide either of $y$ or $z$ or both.  These must be treated separately.

---

> Suppose $3\mid z\implies 3\mid x-y$

This is the same assumption you started the first part of the proof with written in a different way.

> and note: $\gcd(x-y,z^3/(x-y))=\gcd(x-y,(x^3-y^3)/(x-y))=\gcd(x-y,3x^2)=3$

You seem to be making the same mistake as before.  The assumption $3\mid z\implies 3\mid x-y$ does not mean the same thing as the assumption $3\mid z$ *and* $3\mid x-y$.  The assumption $3\mid z\implies 3\mid x-y$ is the same as the assumption $3\nmid z$ *or* $3\mid x-y$.

Ignoring division by zero errors because a division by zero error would imply that one of our variables was zero (*which still should be pointed out during the proof, not left to the reader to notice on their own*), making it to $\gcd(x-y,z^3/(x-y))=\gcd(x-y,3x^2)$ is fine.  As written however, your assumption was not explicitly that $3\mid x-y$, it could still be that $3\nmid z$ and $3\nmid x-y$ in which case $\gcd(x-y,3x^2)=3$ is false.  If we change your hypothesis to be $3\mid z$ and $3\mid x-y$ instead we continue:

> So we know $9\nmid x-y$

What?  Where did this come from?  Knowing that $3$ is the greatest common divisor between $x-y$ and $3x^2$ doesn't directly imply that $9$ is not a divisor of $x-y$.  It could be that $9$ is a divisor of $x-y$ but not a divisor of $3x^2$.

> Take the following equation $(x-y)^3+3y(x-y)^2+3y^3(x-y)=x^3-y^3=z^3\equiv 0\pmod{27}$
>
> $\implies 3y^2(x-y)\equiv 0\pmod{27}\implies 3\mid y$ contradicting $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$

This follows from your given work and (*modified*) assumptions so far, but this does not cover many of the remaining cases.

Comment: I find your answer too lengthy and it leaves quite a negative impression. Although you make a few good arguments your answer is more than twice the length of my proof which is exaggerated. A few 'to the point' comments would have sufficed.

Comment: @zippy I tried that.  You chose to ignore them saying "if these are your only arguments then I am satisfied"